# Update data based on previous row combination values

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a MySQL table with the following structure:

ID 
CatLevel1 CatLevel2 CatLevel3 ... CatLevel6 AcctLevel1 AcctLevel2 ... AcctLevel6
(6 columns for CatLevel, from 1 to 6) and 6 columns for AcctLevel, from 1 to 6).

Beginning with AcctlLevel1, I need to update it depending on the values found in the Catelevel fields in the following manner:

Begin iteration on CatLevel1. Initial value for AcctLevel1 -> 01.
If CatLevel1 Row(n) <> CatLevel1 Row(n-1) then AcctLevel1 -> 02.
meaning that each time a new value (not matching the previous row) is found in CatLevel1, increase the AcctLevel1 by 1 also adding a leading zero for values less than 10.

When the last row in CatLevel1 has been iterated, then begin with CatLevel2 and iterate through it in the same manner.

I was wondering which way to go, to break it down in smaller pieces and code it with PHP or to do it all in MySQL with some sort or recursiveness?

Many of you will think I'm asking for the solution, but I'm really asking for some ideas to get me started because I'm a bit confused on how to go.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement I've come with with the following.

- The first Update does a necessary reset.
- The second causes `AcctLevel1` to be 1 whenever there is a change with the previous row.
- The third Update sums up these 1 to create the final result.

**Data:**

```
create table data
(
id int,
CatLevel1 varchar(5),
AcctLevel1 varchar(5)
);

insert into data values (0,'1','0');
insert into data values (1,'2','0');
insert into data values (2,'1','1');
insert into data values (3,'2','1');
insert into data values (4,'2','1');
```

**SQL Commands:**

```
UPDATE `data` t1 SET AcctLevel1 = 0;

update `data` t1
             left outer JOIN `data` t2
             on t1.id-1 = t2.id
set t1.AcctLevel1 = 
case when t1.CatLevel1 = t2.CatLevel1 then  t1.AcctLevel1 
else  t2.AcctLevel1+1 end;

update `data` t1
set t1.AcctLevel1 =
( select SUM(TEMP.AcctLevel1) from (SELECT *FROM `data`) AS TEMP where TEMP.ID <= t1.ID );
```

- **SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fb647/2
- **2ND SQL Fiddle:**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c047bc/1

### Update: Final Toy Query

```
UPDATE `data` t4
SET AcctLevel1 =
  (
    SELECT CASE WHEN TEMP.SCHANGES IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TEMP.SCHANGES END from
         (SELECT T3.ID,
           (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t1.CatLevel1 = t2.CatLevel1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS SUM_CHANGES
            FROM `data` t1,
                        `data` t2
            WHERE t1.id-1 = t2.id
            AND t1.ID <= t3.ID) AS SCHANGES
         FROM `DATA` t3 ) as TEMP where TEMP.ID = T4.ID
  );
```

**Final JSFiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/325f16/2

Comment: Not a bad thought. However, in my case I'm not inserting data, I'm simply reading and updating it.